# ASP.NET MVC3 custom RoleProvider and Authorize tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I am in the process of learning MVC3 and have implemented my own MembershipProvider and RoleProviders in my project to utilise an existing database's tables that are currently used in a winforms applications login and access restriction system.

Everything works as expected, however I think I might be doing something wrong with regards to the `[Authorize]` tag on controller's actions.

Restriction works fine if I use something like this:
`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Purchaser")]`

However the names of the Roles "Admin" and "Purchaser" are in my database Role table, and it seems 'wrong' that I hard-coded them into this `Authorize` tag. This would mean if I added a new Role in the database table, then I would have to go and change the `Authorize` tags too where relevant.

Its not like Roles in the database will change often, it just seems a little 'rigid' to me.

So my question is, am I doing this correctly? Is there a better way to do it, or is it just the standard way of utilising this system in an MVC project?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The default authorization model is not flexible. But you can make it flexible without much trouble since you already have custom `RoleProvider`.

The trick is to use an intermediate entity `Group` between `User` and `Role`. Users belong to group(s) and Groups have Role(s). Using this you can retrieve the Roles a particular user is in and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining it. I'm still getting used to the use of 'hard coded' string during programming. In winforms I hardly ever had them!

Comment: @AlexTyman With the intermediate entity `Group` a controller action would require only single `Role`. You can remove the hard coded strings by inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` and take enum value value.